# We need a PageSetupDialog which layout and style is the same in Notepad, how to do it?

Tags: c#

We already know System.Windows.Forms.PageSetupDialog, but its layout and style is not the same in Notepad, and we need a page setup dialog in Notepad. how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to modify the PageSetupDialog using Reflection and some unholy techniques but that's not the right solution here.

What you probably want to do is build yours from scratch so that it matches the look and feel that you need.